# Help with audio visualizer

Tags: qt, audio, visualization, visualizer

Im new to this website, and mostly to any type of programming. Recently Im trying to learn C++(Game Programming), and my father wants me to make him a web-based application, that flashes the window wether there is any sound playing(I believe it's called an audio visualization), I talked to my brother, and he said that I should do an external application in C++ or Java. He lend me a book about GUI with QT, but the problem is I don't know how or where to start with, Im installing the QT, although I dont know how to add a library to Microsoft Visual C++(I tried but I had some problems, hopefully qt will do everything automatically), but I wanted to know if anyone has any advice,suggestion or any help to give me. Im pretty much a beginner, this will be my 1st application ever made(with C++ at least) and Im really scared. Thank you for the time wasted reading this, I know I wrote a lot, but I wanted to be the more descriptive I could.

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: I don't want to discourage you, but if you are a complete beginner, you might want to try a language that is a bit more forgiving than C++, such as C#. You'll always be able to go back to C++ once you've gotten some experience (think of C# as C++ but with a net stopping your fall :). And by the way, your brother is right, you can't do a web-based audio visualizer because (as far as I know) the browser cannot "peek" into what the computer sound's system is playing.

Comment: But, wouldn't it be longer to learn to program in C#(as it probably happens with any new language)? I already know the basics of C++, read some books,etc...could you give me some help with a library which I could use for the audio handling, Im usin QT for the GUI and Im liking it :P, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I don't want to put you off either, but that's a *big* undertaking: learning C++, Qt, graphics and then trying to work out how to hook into the audio subsystem (that itself is really not trivial).  I would seriously suggest a simpler project while you grapple with the basics.  As a novice programmer I would also suggest looking at C# as I think it'll give you a better introduction to OOP, and then take a look at C++ when you're more confident as a coder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bit late, but they are right.

Though, if you really want to, I would look into FMOD.

Here's an example using FMOD & OpenGL.

http://segfaultlabs.com/devlogs/sound-equalizer-with-fmod-and-opengl

If that's what you're looking for, if not, email me I am sure I could help you out!